# (Tensorflow Flow Setup) ImportError: No module named tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tensorflow

I'm not able to complete the setup instructions through the [Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac) using pip3, Python 3.6, and mac Sierra v10.12.6.

Attempting to validate the install results in the following:

```
Installing collected packages: protobuf, tensorflow
Successfully installed protobuf-3.5.2.post1 tensorflow-1.8.0
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

➜  python3.6 python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
>>> import Tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Tensorflow
>>> import tensorflow-1.8.0 as tf
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    import tensorflow-1.8.0 as tf
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Please post the results of `pip3 -V`.

Comment: @ArjunAthreya I wasn't able to install the virtualenv. This is my first time using Python and Tensorflow. Do I need virtualenv to work on this codelab? https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/

Comment: I see that you got your problem fixed, but in the future, in my opinion, highly recommend using a virtualenv so you can isolate your environment and packages from the entire system (as to not install something system wide). It will make things a whole lot easier especially when running code and having multiple projects with different packages required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that when you run `python` you get `Python 2.7.10` which is not the version that you installed the TensorFlow library for. Try running `python3` or make sure you are running Python-3x before importing `import tensorflow as tf`.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you, nuric.